# Как вывести данные заказа в админ панель wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть страница заказа куда можно вводить данные и заказывать товар, как мне сделать чтобы введенные данные пользователем формировались в запись на странице заказа в админ панеле Wordpress.
Товар у меня один, поэтому устанавливать плагины для интернет магазинов слишком громоздко.

Answer (score 1):

> как мне сделать чтобы введенные данные пользователем формировались в
>   запись на странице заказа в админ панеле Wordpress.

Для подобных "записей" нужно создать [кастомный тип контента](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_post_types#Custom_Post_Types).
На фронте нужно иметь форму, которая будет заполнять этот тип.

Comment: Спасибо! Кастомный тип я создал, а вот как привязать форму к этому типу ума не приложу, можете подсказать?

Comment: Просто "как" - не проблема, а "как лучше/правильнее" - это зависит от нескольких вещей. Продолжим на оф. форуме. Там удобнее.